# How to preserve formatting while copy-pasting from Eclipse IDE to PowerPoint 2010

Tags: eclipse, copy-paste, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Is there a way I could copy the source code from Eclipse IDE and paste it on PowerPoint preserving the formatting?

When I try to do it I get zero indentation when pasting it to PowerPoint 2010.

The copy-paste from Eclipse to Microsoft Word works just fine, but not with PowerPoint.

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386299/eclipse-copy-code-with-syntax-highlighting In my case I had folded code and copying did not keep the formatting. To solve it, make sure you unfold all code, as shown on: http://cmanios.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/copypaste-source-code-from-eclipse-to-microsoft-word/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of office, there are always the three options available while pasting in any office product, they are

1. Use Destination Theme.
2. Keep Source Formatting. (suitable for your case)
3. Keep Text Only.

However, I would suggest if you are doing this for only presentation purpose, you should take screenshots from eclipse and use them with suitable styles in your presentation. Hope this helps.

Comment: For some reasons I lose the indentation in the formatting when I paste the code into power point, 2010. but the coloring remains intact.

Answer (score 1):

If I paste from Eclipse straight to PowerPoint I get some format mistakes. Some things stay bold or colored. But if you go from Eclipse to Word and then copy from Word to PowerPoint then the formatting is preserved. This is true for PowerPoint 2013 too.

Answer (score 0):

1. From Eclipse, make sure that the selected **contains no folded code**.
2. In Power Point, when pasting, select **keep source formatting**.